# How to hide these two controls in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, mfc

To save screen space, I wanna close some useless controls in my Visual Studio 2008. How to close these two?

[The picture http://img.my.csdn.net/uploads/201303/19/1363672197_5037.png](http://img.my.csdn.net/uploads/201303/19/1363672197_5037.png)

Comment: I think this may be 2010 but it's worth a gander - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2007/12/05/did-you-know-how-to-reach-the-navigation-bar-via-the-keyboard.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Navigation Bar.

You can change settings by entering the Options dialog via the menu (Tools -> Options).  Under Text Editor settings, choose the language (C/C++) and uncheck the Navigation Bar option.

You can do this under the All Languages setting instead, but I wouldn't recommend it.  I disagree with your opinion that it's a "useless control".

[image: Options menu]

Note that after changing it, you may need to close and open your source files again.  I had erratic behaviour on open source files when applying this option.